# `PAM: Authentication failure` when running `chpasswd` on Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am running Alpine Linux like this:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine sh
```

Then running the following commands:

```
/ # apk add shadow
/ # /usr/sbin/useradd -m -u 1000 jenkins
Creating mailbox file: No such file or directory
/ # echo "jenkins:mypassword" | chpasswd
Password: chpasswd: PAM: Authentication failure
```

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/522556/how-to-create-linux-account-with-useradd-without-creating-mail-spool), the warning `Creating mailbox file: No such file or directory` can be safely ignored.

My problem is that `chpasswd` is failing with the vague error message seen in the last line. I tried the exact commands on CenstOS and Ubuntu and it worked there.

Comment: For me it works like a charm (ArchLinux, kernel `5.0.0-arch1-1-ARCH`, docker `18.09.3-ce`). Did you try this on different systems (e.g. in VMs with different distros/kernels)?

Comment: @DanilaKiver I'm using CentOS7, Docker 1.13.1. Haven't tried a different system

Comment: Uh, looks like it is image-specific issue. I had a stale `alpine:latest` on my box. After pulling the new version I reproduced it too both on CentOS7 VM and Arch box. Looks like the issue appeared between `alpine:3.5` and `alpine:3.6` images.

Comment: You're right. I tried `alpine:3.5` and that worked. I think I can use that as a base image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Alpine 3.6+. A new pull request is supposed to have fixed this as mentioned here: https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/10209

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the root account is enable ?
This might be a consequence of this change: https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/commit/72c7a7a3caf28c06289dc5f65e1756b38cfb00ca